# CakePHP: Show other field instead of id

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working in a web aplication for board role playing games management. Its very simple for now.
I have 3 tables:

```
(1) Game
    *  id
    *  title
    *  user_id (game master)

(2) Sheet
    * id
    * name
    * game_id
    * user_id

(3) Users
    * id
    * username
```

Well, I have two problems:

1 - In Sheet view, i cant show the game tittle or the user name, just his id's
2 - In Game view, I cant show the user name (the game master).

I try a lot of answers found here for similar problems, but nothing works. I'm i little bit frustrated :( please help.

Here my code details:

**MODELS:**

```
/*User Model*/    
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array(
      'Sheet' => array(
          'className' => 'Sheet',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
      ),
      'Game' => array(
          'className' => 'Game',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
      )
    );
}
/*Game Model*/
class Game extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Game';
    public $belongsTo = array(
      'Master' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
      )
    );

    public $hasMany = array (
      'Chars' => array (
          'className' => 'Sheet',
          'foreignKey' => 'game_id' 
      )
    );
}
/*Sheet Model*/
class Sheet extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Sheet';
    public $belongsTo = array (
      'Party' => array (
          'className' => 'Game',
          'foreignKey' => 'game_id' 
      ),
      'Player' => array (
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'   
      )
    );
}
```

**CONTROLLERS:**

```
/*SheetController*/
 class SheetController extends AppController {
     public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    var $name = 'Sheets';
 public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Sheet->id = $id;
    $this->Sheet->recursive = 2;
    if (!$this->Ficha->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('La ficha no existe'));
    }
    $this->set('sheet', $this->Sheet->read(null, $id));
}
}
class PartidasController extends AppController {
     public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

     var $name = 'Partidas';
public function view($id) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $this->Partida->recursive=2;
    $partida = $this->Partida->findById($id);
    if (!$partida) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $this->set('partida', $partida);
}
}
```

**VIEWS:**

```
/*Game View*/
<?php echo $game['Game']['title']; ?>
<strong>Master: </strong>
                <?php
                echo $this->Html->link($game['Game']['user_id'], array('controller' => 'Users','action' => 'view',$game['Game']['user_id'])); ?>
/*Sheet View*/
<?php echo $this->Html->link($sheet['Sheet']['nombreFicha'],array('controller' => 'sheets', 'action' => 'view', $sheet['Sheet']['id']));?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($sheet['Sheet']['user_id'],array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $sheet['Sheet']['user_id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($sheet['Sheet']['game_id'],array('controller' => 'games', 'action' => 'view', $sheet['Sheet']['game_id'])); ?>
```

Comment: Can you put the code of the controllers and the views? The problem is probably happening in there

Comment: Your model names don't match up to what you've supplied. Can you post the other relevant models too? I often find that Cake's foreign keys are hard to deal with, so I normally set `'foreignKey' => false` and `'conditions' => 'ModelName.other_model_id = OtherModel.id'` etc instead. According to what you've said here, your User model `hasMany` Games and Sheets, your Game model `hasOne` User and your Sheet model `hasOne` User and Game. Try those basic associations and query from each model to ensure they are working, then add the extra associations in as needed.

Comment: Edited the main post @vicocamacho

Comment: I will try with your option @scrowler